# Palindrome Number Program in C

Tags: c++, if-statement, palindrome

I'm trying to make a C program that determines whether a five-digit integer is a palindrome or not. The part I'm struggling with is not using a loop, as I know how to do it with a loop. However, I'm supposed to do it without one, and instead use nested if else statements of some sorts. I've figured out how to reverse a 3 digit number but not 5, and then going on from there. Here is what I have so far. I'm just learning so it's a bit harder as well.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e , num, reversed;
    cout << "\n Enter a five digit number";
    cin >> num;
    a = num / 100;
    b = (num % 100) / 10;
    c = num % 10;
    d = num % 10;
    e = num % 10;
    reversed = 100 * c + 10 * b + a;
    cout << " " << reversed;
    return 0;
}
```

Again, I can't get it to work for 5 digits but I assume after that using if else statements I can relate reversed and the original number with % to see if it's a palindrome.

Comment: You should loop is such case and not bound your program logic to number of digits in the number.

Comment: Why are you using C++ I/O in a program where the question is tagged C?  That's a serious mismatch.

Comment: You have `d` and `e` which looks like you've started on a 5-digit version.  What's the problem with extending the three-digit code to handle five digits?

Comment: Suggest input validation, e.g. `if (!(cin >> num)) { cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }` otherwise *Undefined Behavior* results on inadvertent non-integer input.

Comment: Have you considered reading in a string or converting the number into a string. you can then access the digits as elements of a char array removing all that pesky low level modulo fiddling.

Comment: @Johannes: the string solution is also very good, and is ideal when paired with loops. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
num = numInput;

a = num % 10; num /= 10;
b = num % 10; num /= 10;
c = num % 10; num /= 10;
d = num % 10; num /= 10;
e = num % 10;

reversed = ((((( a * 10) + b ) * 10 + c ) * 10 + d ) * 10 ) + e;

isPalindrome = ( (numInput == reversed) ? 1 : 0 );
```

Or if you want some "symmetry" of the code (definitely not needed):

```
rev = 0;
rev += a; rev *= 10;
rev += b; rev *= 10;
rev += c; rev *= 10;
rev += d; rev *= 10;
rev += e;
```

But using a loop is much better.

Comment: What is `num` in `isPalindrome = ( (num == reversed) ? 1 : 0 );`?? (hint: `0`)

Comment: @David: :))) you got me here, it is supposed to be the original num :D

Comment: corrected answer as per comment from @David. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I figured, no big deal `:)`

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no change made to your variable `num` in these statements:

```
c = num % 10;
d = num % 10;
e = num % 10;
```

You are not updating `num` at all and hence the values of the variables `c`, `d` and `e` are the same. Hence after taking one modulus, you should divide your `num` variable by 10 as well to move one digit back.

```
a = num % 10;  // get the last digit of num
num /= 10;     // update the last digit (num reduced by 1 digit, '12345' will become '1234')
b = num % 10;
num /= 10;
c = num % 10;
num /= 10;
d = num % 10;
num /= 10;
e = num % 10;

cout << a << b << c << d << e << endl;
```

Since you are only printing the reversed number in your code, you don't need to construct the reversed number again. But if you do, it's quite trivial once you have the digits.

```
reversed = 10000 * a + 1000 * b + 100 * c + 10 * d + e;
```

I believe you can check if the number is a palindrome or not from here on (`isPalindrome = (reversed == num)`).

Comment: How does your code verify if the number is palindrome? Not to say that your code is mostly identical to mine.

Comment: First, I only correct the error in logic to reverse the number which is what OP is doing in his code. He hasn't written anything for checking and hence, I didn't provide any. We are not here to write solutions for askers, but to fix what's wrong with what they have done already. Second, your code is so trivial anyone can come with it. @virolino

Comment: Subject is: `Palindrome Number Program in C`. First sentence is: `I'm trying to make a C program that determines whether a five-digit integer is a palindrome or not.` And OP's program is definitely broken & unfinished.

Comment: Like I said, we don't *write* code for programmers, we *correct* what's wrong with it. If the OP intends to check if it's a palindrome, he should provide the code for that as well. @virolino

Comment: From what you say, I can understand the following: if a code sequence does not work because it is missing a few lines to make it work, we do not provide those lines, because the op did not provide place-holders for them?

Comment: '*if a code sequence does not work because it is missing a few lines to make it work*' that's not the case here, the error was in constructing the reversed number, not in checking if it's a palindrome :) @virolino

Answer (score 0):

You *must* use a loop if you want solution to be smart. And you *should* use pointers if you want solution to be universal (with a couple of changes you can adapt palindrome check to any word/phrase, because palindromes **are not** only numbers). Something like that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int num;
    cout << "\n Enter integer:\n";
    cin >> num;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    const char * itss = ss.str().c_str(); 
    const char * ites = itss + strlen(itss) - 1;
    int is_palindrome = 1;
    while (itss <= ites) {
     if (*itss != *ites) {
      is_palindrome = 0;
      break;
     }
     itss++;
     ites--;
    }
    cout << "your number is " << (is_palindrome ? "a palindrome" : "NOT a palindrome") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
  int n,m,d,s=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  m=n;
  while(m!=0){
    d=m%10;
    s=(s*10)+d;
    m=m/10;
  }
  if(r==n){
    printf("%d is palindrome",n);
  }else{
    printf ("%d is not palindrome",n);
  }
}
```

Just follow a simple digit extraction algorithm all the programs such as palindrome, reverse, sum of digits.... can easily be solved

Comment: Just follow a simple digit extraction algorithm all the programs such as palindrome, reverse,sum of digits....can easily be silved

Comment: When answering a question add all relevant information in the answer and not as comments. You should also explain how this works as dumping a piece of code does not usually help that much.